# how to gather Instruments memory/zombies data after removing & restarting app in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, instruments, nszombie

How can I gather Instruments memory/zombies data after removing app in simulator and restarting in simulator?

What I see in the simulator after I remove the app process, and then retart it by clicking on it's icon in the simulator, is that Instruments has stopped receiving the data from the application?

Background

- I'm trying to test saving and loading data via NSUserDefaults.  After saving it to test the loading part I need to simulate removing the app from memory, so what I have been doing is manually removing the app process on the simulator (double click on menu button etc).
- What I'm finding is that when I do run up the app this way there is some problem at start up - getting "Thread 1 - Program received signal SIGKILL" against the " int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);" line of code
- Therefore I thought I would try to run in Instruments to track down the issue, hence my question as Instruments seems to "stop recording" after I kill the app process on the simulator and then restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible (i.e. no answers yet so I'm guessing the correct answer may be that it's not possible)